# PHP font for Arbaic OCR

Tags: php, arrays, ocr, arabic, persian

This is a PHP code for including latin numbers in an array .

Now I want to add Persian / Arabic numbers to it .

```
<?php
  $char_global_mas[] = Array (
            Array("char"=>Array(
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,2,3,5,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,8,8,7,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,8,8,8,7,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,9,8,6,4,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,3,5,7,8,8,7,5,4,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,8,9,8,6,3,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,2,4,7,8,8,6,4,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,4,6,8,9,7,4,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,3,6,8,8,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,7,8,8,6,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,2,4,7,8,7,5,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,7,4,2,0,0),
                Array(0,1,2,5,8,8,6,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,6,8,8,5,2,1,0),
                Array(0,1,3,6,8,8,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,8,8,6,3,1,0),
                Array(0,1,3,6,8,7,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,7,8,6,3,1,0),
                Array(0,2,4,7,8,6,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,6,8,7,4,2,0),
                Array(1,2,5,7,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,5,2,1),
                Array(1,2,5,8,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(1,2,5,8,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(1,2,5,8,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(1,3,6,8,8,6,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,3,1),
                Array(1,2,6,8,8,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,3,1),
                Array(1,3,5,8,8,6,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,3,1),
                Array(1,3,5,8,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,6,8,8,5,3,1),
                Array(1,2,5,8,8,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(1,2,5,8,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(1,2,5,8,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(1,2,5,8,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,5,2,1),
                Array(0,2,4,7,8,6,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,6,8,7,4,2,0),
                Array(0,1,3,6,8,7,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,7,8,6,3,1,0),
                Array(0,1,3,6,8,8,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,8,8,6,3,1,0),
                Array(0,1,2,5,8,8,6,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,6,8,8,5,2,1,0),
                Array(0,0,2,4,7,8,8,5,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,7,8,7,4,2,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,3,6,8,8,7,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,8,8,6,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,2,4,7,9,8,6,4,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,4,6,8,8,7,4,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,3,6,8,9,8,7,5,4,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,8,8,7,5,3,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,2,4,6,8,9,8,8,7,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,8,7,5,3,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,5,3,2,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
            ), "size"=>Array(28,40)),
            Array("char"=>Array(
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,3,4,5,3,1,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,7,4,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,3,5,8,9,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,2,3,5,8,10,11,9,6,3,1),
                Array(0,0,0,1,2,4,6,8,10,12,12,9,6,2,1),
                Array(0,1,1,3,4,6,8,10,11,12,12,9,6,3,1),
                Array(1,2,3,5,7,8,9,10,11,11,11,9,6,2,1),
                Array(2,4,6,7,9,9,8,8,9,10,10,9,6,2,1),
                Array(3,5,7,8,8,7,6,6,7,8,9,9,6,2,1),
                Array(3,6,7,7,6,4,4,3,5,7,9,8,6,3,1),
                Array(3,4,5,4,3,2,2,2,4,6,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,6,8,8,5,3,1),
                Array(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,6,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,6,3,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,3,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,6,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,6,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,6,3,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,3,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,7,7,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,5,5,4,2,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,3,2,1,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
            ), "size"=>Array(15,40)),
            Array("char"=>Array(
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,2,4,5,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,3,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,3,5,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,3,5,7,8,8,8,7,6,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,9,8,6,4,2,1,0),
                Array(0,1,2,5,7,8,8,7,6,4,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,8,9,8,6,3,1,0),
                Array(1,2,4,6,8,8,7,5,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,4,6,8,9,7,4,2,1),
                Array(1,3,5,8,8,7,4,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,7,8,8,6,3,1),
                Array(1,3,6,8,7,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,7,4,2),
                Array(1,3,6,7,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,7,9,8,5,2),
                Array(1,2,4,4,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2),
                Array(0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2),
                Array(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,5,2),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,7,8,7,4,2),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,7,8,6,3,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,8,7,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,8,6,4,2,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,7,7,4,2,1,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,7,7,5,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,8,7,5,3,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,8,7,5,3,1,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,6,7,7,5,3,2,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,6,7,7,5,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,3,5,6,7,6,5,3,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,5,6,7,6,5,3,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,5,7,7,6,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,7,7,6,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,3,4,6,7,7,6,4,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,3,5,6,7,7,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,3,5,7,8,7,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,1,3,5,7,8,8,6,4,3,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(1,2,5,7,9,9,8,6,4,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0),
                Array(2,4,7,10,11,10,9,7,5,4,3,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,0),
                Array(3,6,9,11,12,11,10,8,7,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,3,2,1),
                Array(3,6,9,11,11,11,10,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,5,3,1),
                Array(3,6,8,9,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,5,3,1),
                Array(2,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,3,2,1),
                Array(1,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,1,0),
                Array(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)
            ), "size"=>Array(25,40)),
            Array("char"=>Array(
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,2,4,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,3,5,7,8,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,9,8,7,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,1,3,5,7,8,9,8,7,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,9,8,7,4,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(1,2,5,7,8,8,7,6,4,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,8,9,8,7,4,2,1,0,0),
                Array(2,4,6,8,8,7,5,3,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,4,6,8,9,8,6,3,1,0,0),
                Array(2,5,7,8,7,4,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,8,9,7,4,2,0,0),
                Array(3,5,6,6,4,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,7,9,8,5,2,1,0),
                Array(2,4,5,4,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2,1,0),
                Array(1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2,1,0),
                Array(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,5,2,1,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,7,8,7,4,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,6,7,7,5,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,4,5,7,7,6,4,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,8,8,7,5,3,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,4,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,8,9,10,10,10,9,7,4,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,8,9,9,9,9,8,7,5,3,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,6,5,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,7,7,6,5,2,1,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,5,7,8,6,4,2,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,8,8,6,3,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,7,8,7,4,2),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,7,8,8,5,2),
                Array(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2),
                Array(1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2),
                Array(2,4,5,4,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,5,2),
                Array(3,5,7,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,7,8,7,4,2),
                Array(3,6,8,8,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,3,6,8,8,6,3,1),
                Array(2,5,8,9,8,6,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,5,7,8,7,4,2,1),
                Array(1,4,7,9,9,8,6,4,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,4,6,7,8,8,6,3,1,0),
                Array(1,2,5,7,9,9,8,7,5,4,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,8,9,8,7,4,2,1,0),
                Array(0,1,3,5,7,9,9,9,8,7,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,9,8,7,4,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,3,5,7,8,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,9,8,7,6,4,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
            ), "size"=>Array(25,40)),
            Array("char"=>Array(
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,3,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,6,5,3,2,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,8,7,5,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,8,10,10,9,5,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,7,10,12,12,9,6,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,6,9,11,13,12,10,6,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,8,10,12,12,12,9,6,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,7,9,10,11,11,11,9,6,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,8,9,9,9,10,10,9,6,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,6,8,8,7,7,7,9,9,9,6,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,8,7,6,5,5,7,9,8,6,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,7,7,5,4,3,4,6,8,8,6,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,7,7,7,5,3,2,2,3,6,8,8,5,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,8,7,5,3,2,1,1,3,6,8,8,6,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,2,3,6,8,8,6,3,2,1,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,8,6,4,2,1,0,0,1,3,5,8,8,5,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,2,5,7,8,7,5,2,1,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,2,4,6,8,7,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,8,8,5,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,1,2,4,6,8,8,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,6,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,1,3,5,7,8,7,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,6,3,1,0,0),
                Array(1,3,5,7,9,8,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,6,3,1,0,0),
                Array(2,5,7,9,9,8,6,4,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,4,7,9,9,7,4,2,1,0),
                Array(4,7,9,11,10,9,7,5,4,3,3,2,2,3,3,4,6,9,10,10,9,6,4,2,1),
                Array(5,8,11,12,11,10,8,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,9,11,12,12,10,8,6,4,2),
                Array(5,8,10,11,11,10,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,10,12,13,13,12,10,8,6,3),
                Array(4,6,8,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,11,12,13,13,12,10,8,6,3),
                Array(2,4,5,6,6,6,6,5,6,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,9,11,12,12,10,8,6,4,2),
                Array(1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,4,6,9,10,10,9,6,4,2,1),
                Array(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,4,7,9,9,7,4,2,1,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,6,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,6,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,5,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,7,7,5,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,5,5,3,2,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,3,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
            ), "size"=>Array(25,40)),
            Array("char"=>Array(
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,3,4,5,5,6,5,5,6,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,3,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,3,5,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,5,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,2,4,7,9,10,10,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,5,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,2,5,8,10,10,8,7,6,6,5,6,6,5,6,5,5,5,3,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,3,5,8,9,8,6,4,3,3,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,3,6,8,8,6,4,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,4,6,8,7,5,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,2,4,7,8,6,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,1,2,5,7,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,1,3,6,8,8,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,1,3,6,8,7,5,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,2,4,7,9,8,5,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(1,2,5,8,9,8,6,5,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(1,2,6,9,10,10,8,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,7,7,6,5,4,2,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(1,3,6,9,11,11,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,3,1,0,0,0),
                Array(1,3,6,9,11,11,9,8,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,7,5,3,1,0,0),
                Array(1,3,6,8,9,9,7,5,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,7,4,2,1,0),
                Array(1,2,4,6,6,6,4,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,4,6,7,8,6,4,2,0),
                Array(0,1,2,3,3,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,8,7,5,2,1),
                Array(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,7,8,6,3,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,7,8,7,4,2),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,5,2),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2),
                Array(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,5,2),
                Array(2,3,3,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,7,8,7,4,2),
                Array(3,5,6,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,7,8,6,3,1),
                Array(3,6,7,7,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,8,7,5,2,1),
                Array(3,5,7,8,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,5,7,8,6,4,1,0),
                Array(2,4,6,8,7,6,4,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,4,5,7,7,7,4,2,1,0),
                Array(1,2,4,7,8,7,6,5,4,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,5,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,1,3,5,7,8,8,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,7,5,3,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,3,4,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,3,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,2,4,5,6,7,7,8,8,8,7,7,6,5,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
            ), "size"=>Array(25,40)),
            Array("char"=>Array(
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,4,5,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,2,3,5,7,8,8,7,7,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,9,8,6,4,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,3,6,7,8,8,6,5,4,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,8,9,8,6,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,3,5,7,9,8,6,4,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,4,6,8,8,7,4,2,1,0),
                Array(0,1,2,4,7,9,8,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,7,7,5,2,1,0),
                Array(0,1,3,6,8,9,7,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,5,6,4,2,1,0),
                Array(0,2,4,7,9,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,3,3,2,1,0),
                Array(1,2,5,8,9,7,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                Array(1,3,6,8,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(1,3,6,8,7,5,2,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(2,4,7,8,7,4,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(2,5,8,8,7,4,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(2,5,8,9,7,5,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,7,6,5,3,2,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(2,5,9,9,8,6,5,5,5,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(2,6,9,10,10,8,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,9,8,7,5,3,1,0,0),
                Array(2,6,9,11,11,9,8,7,5,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,8,9,9,7,5,2,1,0),
                Array(3,6,9,11,11,10,7,5,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,4,6,8,9,8,6,4,1,0),
                Array(2,6,9,11,11,9,6,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,5,8,9,8,5,2,1),
                Array(3,6,9,11,10,7,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,6,8,8,6,3,1),
                Array(2,6,9,10,8,5,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,7,8,7,4,2),
                Array(2,5,8,9,7,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,5,2),
                Array(2,5,7,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2),
                Array(2,4,7,7,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2),
                Array(1,3,6,7,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2),
                Array(1,2,5,6,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,7,8,8,5,2),
                Array(0,2,4,6,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,8,8,7,4,2),
                Array(0,1,3,5,6,5,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,8,8,6,3,1),
                Array(0,1,2,4,6,6,5,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,6,8,9,7,4,2,1),
                Array(0,0,1,3,5,7,7,5,4,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,4,6,8,9,8,6,3,1,0),
                Array(0,0,1,2,4,6,7,7,6,5,4,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,8,9,8,7,4,2,1,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,2,4,6,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,9,8,7,4,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,2,4,5,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
            ), "size"=>Array(27,40)),
            Array("char"=>Array(
                Array(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                Array(1,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,3,2,2,2,1),
                Array(2,3,5,5,5,6,5,5,6,5,5,6,6,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,5,4,2),
                Array(3,5,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,8,6,3),
                Array(3,5,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,10,10,9,7,4),
                Array(2,3,5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,6,6,6,7,8,9,10,9,6,3),
                Array(1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,3,4,5,6,8,8,7,4,2),
                Array(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,5,6,6,5,3,1),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,5,5,5,3,1,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,5,5,3,2,1,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,6,5,3,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,5,4,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,5,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,6,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,6,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,7,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,6,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,7,7,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,7,7,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,7,7,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,7,7,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,7,7,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,7,7,5,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,7,8,6,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,7,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,5,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,2,4,7,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,2,5,7,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,5,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,2,4,7,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,2,5,7,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,2,4,7,7,5,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,2,3,5,5,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,2,3,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
            ), "size"=>Array(23,40)),
            Array("char"=>Array(
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,2,4,5,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,3,5,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,8,7,6,4,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,2,5,7,8,9,8,7,6,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,9,8,7,4,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,1,2,4,7,9,9,8,6,4,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,8,9,8,7,4,2,1,0),
                Array(0,1,3,6,8,9,8,5,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,4,6,8,9,8,6,3,1,0),
                Array(0,2,4,7,9,8,6,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,6,8,9,7,4,2,0),
                Array(1,2,5,8,9,7,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,7,9,8,5,2,1),
                Array(1,2,5,8,9,7,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,7,9,8,5,2,1),
                Array(1,2,5,8,9,7,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,7,9,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,2,4,7,8,7,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,7,9,8,5,2,1),
                Array(0,1,3,6,8,8,6,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,6,8,9,7,4,2,0),
                Array(0,1,2,5,7,8,7,5,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,5,8,9,8,6,3,1,0),
                Array(0,0,1,3,5,7,8,7,6,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,6,8,9,8,7,4,2,1,0),
                Array(0,0,1,2,4,7,9,9,9,8,7,6,6,6,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,5,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,4,7,9,11,11,10,9,8,8,8,9,9,10,11,11,9,7,4,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,2,4,7,10,11,11,10,9,8,8,8,9,9,10,11,11,9,7,4,2,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,1,3,6,8,10,10,9,8,6,6,6,6,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,5,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,1,2,5,7,9,9,8,6,4,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,7,8,9,9,7,5,2,1,0),
                Array(1,2,4,7,9,9,8,5,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,4,6,8,9,8,6,4,2,0),
                Array(1,3,6,8,9,8,5,3,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,5,8,9,8,5,2,1),
                Array(2,4,7,9,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,3,6,8,8,6,3,1),
                Array(2,5,8,9,7,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,7,8,7,4,2),
                Array(2,5,8,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,5,2),
                Array(2,5,8,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2),
                Array(2,5,8,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,8,5,2),
                Array(2,5,7,8,6,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,6,8,7,5,2),
                Array(2,4,7,8,7,4,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,7,8,7,4,2),
                Array(1,3,6,8,7,5,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,7,8,6,3,1),
                Array(1,2,5,7,8,7,5,3,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,4,7,8,7,5,2,1),
                Array(0,1,4,6,8,8,7,5,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,5,7,8,8,6,4,1,0),
                Array(0,1,2,4,7,8,8,7,6,5,4,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,7,8,8,7,4,2,1,0),
                Array(0,0,1,3,5,6,8,8,8,8,7,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,6,5,3,1,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,1,2,4,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,6,4,2,1,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,6,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
            ), "size"=>Array(26,40))

        );

?>
```

Every source I have read till now was a closed end, is it even possible to add Arabic numbers to it ?!